# Retrofit "HTTP method annotation is required"

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, kotlin-coroutines

Experimenting with Coroutines and Jetpack Compose and getting an unhelpful stacktrace from Retrofit:

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: HTTP method annotation is required (e.g., @GET, @POST, etc.).
        for method PokeApi.getPokeList
```

Retrofit call API (imports are all 2.7.1):

```
  import retrofit2.http.GET
  import retrofit2.http.Path
  import retrofit2.http.Query

interface PokeApi {
    @GET("pokemon")
    suspend fun getPokeList(@Query("limit") limit: Int = 151
    ): PokeListRequest

    @GET("pokemon/{species}")
    suspend fun getPokemon(@Path("species") pokemon: String
    ): PokeRequest

}
```

Network caller:

```
class PokeClient {
    private var gson = Gson()
    private var caller = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
        .build()
        .create(PokeApi::class.java)


    suspend fun getAllPokemon(): PokeListRequest {
        return caller.getPokeList()
    }

    suspend fun lookupPokemon(species: String): PokeRequest {
        return caller.getPokemon(species)
    }

}
```

Call from ViewModel:

```
fun retrieveList() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            PokeClient().getAllPokemon().results.map{it.name}
                .also{pokeList.value = it}
        }
    }
}
```

It's not pretty but I can't see why it shouldn't be working.

Comment: I think that you are running into some of the same problems that Room users do. There are conflicts between annotation processors and the Kotlin changes needed by Compose. Eventually, that will all get fixed. In the meantime, you may need to have your Compose code in a separate module from your Retrofit (and Room) code.

Comment: This was 100% correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Separating the Retrofit caller into a different module solved this issue.